# WSO2 Developer Studio - when is the next version of Eclipse to be released?

Tags: eclipse, wso2

Looking at the WSO2 Developer Studio Downloads website, the latest version of Eclipse they use is `Eclipse JavaEE luna` which was released in 2014.

http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/

It seems rather out of date. However, I can't find any information on future plans for the next release date?

Anyone know any more about this?

Answer (score 0):

The tooling is found for download here now:
http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/#download

Click on download tooling to obtain the tooling.
Currently the tooling is shipped with Eclipse Mars and not Eclipse Luna

Comment: But is Eclipse Mars + Tooling == Developer Studio?

Comment: Yes. The tooling has now been separated from eclipse so that it can be pluggable to Eclipse Mars